# Django : What is the difference between the request and self?

Tags: django

Same as the title. What is the difference between the request and self in Django?

i'd try class based view and function view. and copy well-made code. but I don't know whay is the difference between self in fomr_valid and request in moneylog_delete definition.

```
class moneylog_update(UpdateView):
    model = moneylog_models.Moneylog
    form_class = forms.UpdateMoneylogForm
    template_name = "moneylogs/update.html"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        moneylog = form.save(commit=False)
        moneybook = moneybook_models.Moneybook.objects.get(
            pk=self.kwargs["pk"])
        moneylog.save()
        form.save_m2m()
        return redirect(reverse("moneybooks:detail", kwargs={'pk': moneybook.pk}))


def moneylog_delete(request, moneybook_pk, moneylog_pk):
    user = request.user
    try:
        moneybook = moneybook_models.Moneybook.objects.get(pk=moneybook_pk)
        models.Moneylog.objects.filter(pk=moneylog_pk).delete()
        return redirect(reverse("moneybook:detail", kwargs={"pk": moneybook.pk}))
    except models.Moneylog.DoesNotExist:
        return redirect(reverse("cores:home"))
```

Comment: `request` is an object sent in to a function as a parameter. `self` is the normal way to refer to an instance of a class in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#httprequest-objects) is an object that Django creates each time the real request was made to the view. It contains metadata about the real request and some attributes set by middleware (most commonly used is user instance).
`self` it's a Python way of naming the reference to the instance within the current scope. From doc's:

> Often, the first argument of a method is called self. This is nothing more than a convention: the name self has absolutely no special meaning to Python. Note, however, that by not following the convention your code may be less readable to other Python programmers, and it is also conceivable that a class browser program might be written that relies upon such a convention.

Basically, these are two different things.